# Primefaces selectOneMenu changes value after page refresh in firefox

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am using PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu with change event call.
When I change it's value, the change method calls and sets some parameters. when I refresh the page, in the bean side, selected value changes to default but in the UI, changed value showed. So, when user clicks on the submit, the setter method changes the value but change method don't calls.
Here is UI code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedType}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.types}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.changeType}" update=":form"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.changeType}" update=":form"/>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to the problem? Struggling with the same problem here -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Solve this problem with remoteCommand component, to update selectOneMenu after page is refreshed. Don't forget to set selected variable to null in @PostConstruct method.

The problem occurs only on Firefox browser.

code:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rcName"
                 update="@form"
                 autoRun="true"
                 ignoreAutoUpdate="true" />code
```

Comment: hmm... Do you set selected variable to null in @PostConstruct method?

Comment: It worked. Just add your comment to your answer for acceptance. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem and was able to solve it by adding explicit no-cache instructions to the HTTP-Header.

e.g. implement the javax.servlet.Filter class and do something like

```
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, 
    must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

in the doFilter() method.

Then just apply your filter-class to the pages you want to filter in your web.xml

Comment: thank you! it solved my problem when having a similar issue, but with the selectManyCheckbox component. I upvoted your solution.,, do you know of any possible side effects by using this approach?

Comment: As far as I know it's still working fine in production, so no grave side-effects. It's been a while since I worked with that program though!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your bean is `@RequestScoped`. If so change it to `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: No, it is @ViewScoped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to put `process="@this"` in the ajax component?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was solved via the example in https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/primefaces/select-one-menu-with-ajax.html

The key is that the ajax `change` event isn't well supported (it does not appear to fire the `update`).  Using `itemSelect` instead completely fixed this problem for me.

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="@all"/>
```